extension field in the subring $K[u]$
If $F$ is an extension field of a field $K$, $u, u_i \in F$, and $X \subset F$, then
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item the subring $K[u]$ consists of all elements of the form $f(u)$, where $f$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K$ (that is, $f \in K[x]$).
\end{enumerate}
Proof:
Let $S = \{f(u) : f \in K[x]\}$. We will show that $S$ is a subring of $F$ and $S$ is the smallest subring of $F$ containing $K$ and $u$, that is, $S = K[u]$. Since $0 \in K[x]$, $0 = \sum_{i=0}^n 0x^i$ where $0 \in K$. Thus, $0(u) = \sum_{i=0}^n 0u^i = 0$. It follows that $0 \in S$. Hence, $S \neq \emptyset$. Let $a, b \in S$. Then there exists $f, g \in K[x]$ such that $a = f(u)$ and $b = g(u)$. Since $K[x]$ is a ring, $f - g, fg \in K[x]$. Thus, $a - b = f(u) - g(u) = (f - g)(u)$ where $f - g \in K[x]$. Also, $ab = f(u)g(u) = (fg)(u)$ where $fg \in K[x]$.
Hence, $a - b, ab \in S$. By subring criterion, $S$ is a subring of $F$.
Now, we will show that $S = K[u]$. Let $Y$ be a subring of $F$ containing $\{u\}$ and $K$.
Suppose that $k \in K$. Then $k \in K[x]$. Thus, $k(u) = k$. It implies that $k \in S$. Hence, $K \subset S$. Suppose that $f = x \in K[x]$. Then $f(u) = u$. It follows that $u \in S$. This implies that $K[u] = \bigcap_{K,\{u\}\subset Y} Y \subset S$ where $Y$ is a subring containing $K$ and $\{u\}$.
In that part of proof , why is that if $k \in K$. Then $k \in K[x]$, implies that  $k(u) = k$, also why is it that if $f = x \in K[x]$, then $f(u) = u$. I don't get that part in the proof

$k$ is an element in the ring $K$, so $k$ can also be viewed as a constant polynomial in the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $K$.
In this case, we are just dealing with a function evaluation at $u$. If you evaluate a constant polynomial in any $x$, what would you get?
Likewise, if a polynomial $f$ is defined simply as $f:=x$, what happens if you replace $x$ with $u$?
